# Keyboard suggestion

Tags: keyboards

I've been searching the best mechanical keyboard for coding and writing for quite sometime now. But every option is lacking either one criterion or another. I would prefer:

1. Full sized keyboard, preferably with metal casing.
2. Wired and wireless, with decent battery life.
3. White backlight with shine through keycaps. No need for rgb. I hate rgb.
4. Must support linux distros like ubuntu, kali, arch. Windows layout, because I don't know if linux layout exists or not.
5. Absence of dials or screens would be appreciated.

Also can you suggest should I go for blue switches or brown? Red will not work for me because I need tactile feedback from my keys. I work alone, and don't mind however loud or clicky the keys will be. But I would like thock, which I don't think the clicky switches will offer. I'm buying a mechanical for the first time and don't know if my assumption above is true. I know I'm a bit picky, but when I've got to invest in a keyboard, I want it to be a perfect and long lasting match. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

- In terms of choosing key switches, it's really down to personal preference; unfortunately, the best way to determine that is to try it. You can usually buy smaller quantities of switches from vendors such as Novelkeys and Flashquark. However, based on the fact that you don't seem to mind the noise, I'd probably go for clicky switches, as the bump is more noticeable than with tactile switches. You may want to try Box Navy or Box Jade switches, as these have relatively stiff actuation forces and noticeable bumps.
- Windows-layout and Linux-layout are generally considered identical, but I've picked programmable keyboards when possible in case you want to create custom bindings.

With that in mind, I've got a couple options:

## [Keychron K10 Pro](https://www.keychron.com/products/keychron-k10-pro-qmk-via-wireless-mechanical-keyboard) - $100

[image]

- Full sized traditional 100% layout, **but with a primarily plastic casing**.
- Wired (USB-C) or wireless (Bluetooth 5.1) with a 4000 mAh battery.
- White backlight. **The included keycaps are not shine-through**, but it's a standard layout, so you can use whatever shine-through keycaps appeal to you. Keychron also sells a barebones version without keycaps or switches for $10 less, but apparently only for the RGB version.
- Fully programmable using QMK/VIA.
- No dials or screens.
- Comes with Keychron Brown or Banana tactile switches. Switches are hot-swappable, so you can easily change to something else down the line.

## Keychron Q6 Pro - $190 (barebones), $210 (including keycaps and switches)

[image]

- Full sized traditional 100% layout with an all-metal 6063 aluminum construction.
- Wired (USB-C) or wireless (Bluetooth 5.1) with a 4000 mAh battery.
- **RGB backlight, though you can set it to white mode.** **The included keycaps are not shine-through**, but it's a standard layout, so you can use whatever shine-through keycaps appeal to you. There's also a barebones version available.
- Fully programmable using QMK/VIA.
- **Includes a small dial**, but I personally think it's quite inoffensive.
- Optionally comes with Keychron Brown or Banana tactile switches. Switches are hot-swappable, so you can easily change to something else down the line.

## [Cascade 98%](https://www.aziocorp.com/collections/98-keyboards-1/products/cascade-98-wireless-hot-swappable-keyboard) - $100 (barebones), $130 (including keycaps and switches)

[image]

- **98% keyboard**—compact layout with most of the keys of a full-sized keyboard. Aluminum upper body.
- Wired (USB-C) or wireless (Bluetooth 5.0) with a 4000 mAh battery.
- **RGB backlight, though you can set it to white mode.** Included shine-through keycaps.
- **Not programmable**, though it should still be fine in Linux.
- No dials or screens.
- Optionally comes with Gateron G Pro Brown or Blue switches. Switches are hot-swappable, so you can easily change to something else down the line.